# How do I merge dictionaries in list that have equal value and concate values that are not equal and keep other field in dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

there is list of dictionaries,
when id in two or more dict are equal,names are equal too,but codes are different.

```
[
    {
        "id" : 2.0,
        "name":"x",
        "code" : "12345"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2.0,
        "name":"x",
        "code" : "23456"
    },
    {
        "id" : 4.0,
        "name":"y",
        "code" : "6767"
    },
    {
        "id" : 5.0,
        "name":"z",
        "code" : "567"
    },
    {
        "id" : 4.0,
        "name":"y",
        "code" : "55657"
    }
]
```

I want to merge dict that have common id, then i want to have this list as you can see:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 2.0,
        "name":"x",
        "code" : "12345,23456"
    },
    {
        "id" : 4.0,
        "name":"y",
        "code" : "6767,55657"
    },
    {
        "id" : 5.0,
        "name":"z",
        "code" : "567"
    }
]
```

Comment: Why don't use list instead of appending the string separated with comma?

Comment: beacuse i want use web service and the format of input in this ws is string..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the library `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
# Here, L1 is your former list
L2 = pd.DataFrame(L1).groupby(["id", "name"], as_index=False).agg({"code": lambda x: ','.join(x.tolist())}).to_json(orient="records")
print(L2)
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "id": 2.0,
    "name": "x",
    "code": "12345,23456"
  },
  {
    "id": 4.0,
    "name": "y",
    "code": "6767,55657"
  },
  {
    "id": 5.0,
    "name": "z",
    "code": "567"
  }
]
```

EDIT: Fixed List to String

Answer (score 2):

You should loop through the dictionary like this:

```
dictionary_aux = []
for elem in dictionary:
    found = False
    for new_elem in dictionary_aux:
        if new_elem.id == elem.id:
             new_elem.code = new_elem.code + "," elem.code
             found = True
             break
    if not found:
         dictionary_aux.append(elem)
```

You have the result in dictionary_aux. I hope it helps.